# Creating a FRIEND RELATION in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I am creating a system to keep the relationships in my application. When someone says someone is stored in your database id, and his friend (in that order). And when to the other person accepts the request the id of his friend and the other id (in reverse order) is saved.

To verify that you two are friends have to see that there are these two rows.

The last problem is that when this is true, I have to retrieve the name of a friend from another table .. and do not know how to express it in PHP.

I've been testing, and should be something like this. Here is the code:

```
SELECT nombre FROM users 
JOIN friends WHERE (id=usuari_o OR id=usuari_t) AND 
(usuari_t='$id' OR usuari_o='$id')
```

FRIENDS TABLES STRUCTURE:

[image]

USERS TABLE STRUCTURE:

[image]

Comment: What is the common column between the two tables? id and usuari_o?

Comment: Can you provide sample table structure and data?

Comment: usuari_o and usuari_t ARE id's columns

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT original.nombre as original_nombre, friends.usuari_o, target.nombre as target_nobmre, friends.usuari_t
FROM friends
LEFT JOIN users AS original ON original.id = friends.usuari_od
LEFT JOIN users AS target ON target.id = friends.usuari_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT users.nombre FROM users 
LEFT JOIN friends WHERE 
(users.id=friends.usuari_o OR users.id=friends.usuari_t) AND 
(friends.usuari_two='$id' OR friends.usuari_one='$id')
```

Comment: usuari_two, usuari_one columns are in which table? It not in friends table coz friends table have columns usuari_o & usuari_t

Comment: Still didn't got your requirement

Comment: Oh my god, sorry! usuari_o and usuari_one are the same.. SORRY! AND usuari_two is usuari_t